# PHP registration system error

Tags: php

Hello I have making a registration system, and have come across a few errors:

> Sorry but an error has occurred, please try again
>
> email has invalid characters
>
> submit is required

This is my code:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    require_once 'config.php';
    $errors = [];

    foreach($_POST as $field => $value){
        if(empty($value)){
            //failed
            $errors[] = "{$field} is required";
        }
        if(($field === 'email') && !filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){//check valid email
            //failed
            $errors[] = "{$field} is invalid email";
        }
        if($field !== 'username' && !preg_match('/^[a-z]*$/i', $value)){
            //failed 
            $errors[] = "{$field} has invalid characters";
        }
        if($field === 'username') {
            if (!preg_match('/^[a-z\d_]{4,20}$/i', $value)) {
                $errors[] = "{$field} has invalid characters";
            } else {

                $escaped_username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['username']);
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$escaped_username'";
                $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
                $num_matching_usernames = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                if($num_matching_usernames > 0){
                    $errors[] = "{$field} Username already taken";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // no errors, lets save and send email
    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $hashed_password = password_hash($_POST["password"], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $fields = ['firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'username'];
        $escaped_values = [];
        foreach ($fields as $field) {
            $escaped_values[$field] = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['$field']);
        }
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, email, username, password) VALUES ('{$escaped_values["firstname"]}', '{$escaped_values["lastname"]}', '{$escaped_values["email"]}', '{$escaped_values["username"]}', '$hashed_password')";
        mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
        // send email
        $emailRecipient = $_POST["email"];
        $subject = 'Welcome';
        $message_body = 'You have successfully created an account ' . $_POST["username"] . '! Welcome.';
        mail($emailRecipient, $subject, $message_body);
        header("Location: ../index.php");
        exit;
    }
}

// display errors at top of page
if (count($errors) > 0) {
    echo "Sorry but an error has occurred, please try again";
    echo "<ul>";

    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo "<li>" . htmlentities($error) . "</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
?>
```

I think that the "email has invalid characters" error may be due to the following code:

```
if($field !== 'username' && !preg_match('/^[a-z]*$/i', $value)){
                $errors[] = "{$field} has invalid characters";
<?php
```

But for the "submit is required" error I cant seem to find what is causing it.

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thank you

Comment: `$field !== 'username'` will cause it to be true each time until it is `username`

Comment: To start debugging print out the content of your post array `print_r($_POST);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the submit error, ignore the submit element. To fix the email error, fix the condition of the "invalid character" check.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    require_once 'config.php';
    $errors = [];

    foreach($_POST as $field => $value){
        if($field === 'submit') {
            continue;
        }
        if(empty($value)){
            //failed
            $errors[] = "{$field} is required";
        }
        if(($field === 'email') && !filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){//check valid email
            //failed
            $errors[] = "{$field} is invalid email";
        }
        if($field !== 'username' && $field !== 'email' && !preg_match('/^[a-z]*$/i', $value)){
            //failed 
            $errors[] = "{$field} has invalid characters";
        }
        if($field === 'username') {
            if (!preg_match('/^[a-z\d_]{4,20}$/i', $value)) {
                $errors[] = "{$field} has invalid characters";
            } else {

                $escaped_username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['username']);
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$escaped_username'";
                $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
                $num_matching_usernames = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                if($num_matching_usernames > 0){
                    $errors[] = "{$field} Username already taken";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to help it working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You have an element named submit in your form. For example:

```
<input type="button" name="submit"\>
```

Use html button element instead of input button